# Sequence in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, navicat

I create a model in Navicat and set the id column to serial8 as primary key, but when I snychronize the model with the database tables, it always failed for there is no sequence named **_id_seq, just set the id column to int8.
I don't know why.